# Excel: ISEVEN and text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First I'll explain what I want as result:

If there is an **odd** number in the column "*HOME_TEAM_ID*", I would like to see "**Premier League 1**" in the column "*COMPETITIE*", otherwise I want to have "**Super League 1**"

Now the problem:

I can't find the formula to do this. I tried "=ISEVEN" but that is more like a boolean and will only show me "TRUE" or "FALSE".

I am working on Excel online, don't know if this could affect something.

Thanks for helping.

[image: Excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ISEVEN will return TRUE/FALSE.

So we use IF() to tell the cell what to display based on the outcome of ISEVEN.

```
=IF(ISEVEN(B2),"Super League 1","Premier League 1")
```